# Collection fetch returns one model but response has all models

Tags: backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone and on fetching a collection, I can see the server return all 15 collections.  The fetch success returns all 15 models in the response object but the collection object has only the last of the 15 models.

```
var BracketModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    id: '',
     name: '',
     title: ''
  },
  urlRoot: 'http://test.com/bracket/rest.php',
  .....
  }),

var BracketsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'http://test.com/bracket/rest.php?op=list',
    model: BracketModel,
}),

bracketCollection.fetch({
  success: function (collection, response) {
    // Collection.models only has one model, response has 15
    var bracketsView = new BracketsView({collection: collection});
},
```

Comment: "Collection.models only has one model, response has 15" is a bit strange. Is the JSON being sent to the browser in the correct format and with the correct content-type?

Comment: Thanks for this. The problem did turn out to be with the JSON returned from the server. The id field was null for all of the models in the collection. When I corrected this, everything worked.

Comment: That would do it, the collection expects models to be uniquely identified by their `id` so it was probably seeing the models as 15 copies/versions of one model.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var bracketsView = new BracketsView({collection: response});
```

Or

```
var bracketsView = new BracketsView({collection: collection.toJSON()});
```

I haven't tested it now, but if I remember well, both are equivalent.
The first parameter returns the collection object, which gives you access to different collection attributes.  The second parameter returns 'an array containing the attributes hash of each model in the collection', which is likely the thing you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but neither of those options pass the collection to the view and the view needs access to the collection object.

Comment: Try `var bracketsView = new BracketsView({'collection': response});`  Note the apostrophes.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern that I usually go with for passing a collection to a view goes like this:

```
var bracketCollection = new BracketsCollection();
var view = new brackatsView({collection: bracketCollection});
brackCollection.fetch();
```

Then inside of your view's initialization method do this:

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);
```

What this all is doing is creating your collection and your view, and then when you create the view you are telling it about the collection. Calling fetch on the collection is an asynchronous event that will fire a 'sync' even when it is done. The view will listen for this sync event, and when it happens will call the render function.